# Changed Python 2.7 to Python 3.7 getting TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.7

`response = requests.get(model_req_url, headers=headers, cookies={'googletrans': '/es/en'})
 response_text= response.content.replace("_loadModels(", "").replace(");", "")`

getting error ::
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/zerebralitsolutionpvt.ltd./Projects/autox-misc/url_generator/mobile_de/mobile_de.py", line 81, in 
    response_text= response.content.replace("_loadModels(", "").replace(");", "")
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response.content` returns bytes not string in Python3, change `.content` to `.text` and it should work:

```
response      = requests.get(model_req_url, headers=headers, cookies={'googletrans': '/es/en'})
response_text = response.text.replace("_loadModels(", "").replace(");", "")  # replace .content to .text
```